# Have to count # of records, which database should i use

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-rds

I am designing a system which has a feature in which i have to allow user to create posts and reply to posts (no children to posts). One of the requirement is to show if there are new posts for each forum since user's last visit. Users will be divided in different departments. There could be multiple departments but user would have visibility within respective department. Each department can have upto 1000-1500 users.

The ideal use-case would be to count # of posts since last visit but even if i get yes/no answer about new posts since last visit, it would be okay.

Using and RDS would have been perfect since each post can easily has parent-child relationship. But RDS will cost me $23/month with bare minimum use. Given that this is just a PoC for an idea, i don't want to spend that much per month. So i am looking for alternative.

The other approach is DynamoDB. But DynamoDB doesn't give anything out of the box (at least i am not aware of) to count # of rows since given datetime. I would have read ALL posts for the given time (assuming i make datetime a sortkey along with departmentid as hash key) which would eat up my RCU (read capacity units).

What would be best optimized (cost/operational) way to implement this requirement.

Answer (score 1):

DynamoDB doesn't support counting out-of-box indeed. One of the options would be pre-calculating the number of rows and storing it in a separate entity for fast access. When a new post is created you also increment the total number of posts, and when a user reads the post you increment the number of already read posts by this user. You may use [DDB transactions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/transaction-apis.html) or [DDB streams and Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.Lambda.html) to simplify updates of accumulating entities.

This solution should work but it may be complicated to implement correctly. For simplicity, I'd recommend changing the counting requirement first. You could set a threshold for the counting label, e.g. 100 unread messages. In this case, instead of showing `1521 new messages` label would show `100+ new messages`. This approach is used in the majority of messengers I encounter (e.g., Slack, Discord, etc.).

This way allows you to read only up to 100 next unread messages and it won't consume much of RCUs especially if your entities are small (and they should be small as a general rule). DDB charges for the total size of all items returned by the query. So you may retrieve 100 rows and they still would cost you 0.5 RCU if their combined size is lower than 4096 bytes.

Comment: Thats what i was thinking i.e. changing the approach and i even put that in my question that if counting is difficult then i can work with figuring out if there have been any "new" posts since last visit. And for that even if there is 1 new posts, then should work. But how would i limit # of results return in dynamodb without affecting the RCU? Would using the `limit` operator in boto client is exactly what i am looking for?

Comment: Yes, `limit` will do the job for you. It limits the max count of returned items in response. 


Keep in mind that if you have `FilterExpression` applied in addition to `KeyExpression` then the filter will be applied after reading `limit` number of items. 
Check [this article](https://www.alexdebrie.com/posts/dynamodb-filter-expressions/#how-filter-expressions-actually-work) for more details about filter expressions